# _id value is populating with some random string in 8.9 v while cloning the data from 2.3 using logstatsh

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

logstatsh.conf

```
 input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "XXXXXXXXX"
    index => "mon"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "XXXXXX"
    index => "mon"
    user => "XXXXX"
    password => "XXXXXX"


    }
}
```

`_id` is not getting its data while running the pipeline in Logstash. I want to have the same data of _id in 8.9

for eg:
output 2.3 v has an `_id` value as "yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mi-ss-ms"

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "mon",
        "_id" : "2017-10-23-16.41.22.548866",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
```

output 8.9 v has an _id value as "AwedmdfkgkiAkfkls"

```
"hits" : [

      {
        "_index" : "mon",
        "_id" : "AwedmdfkgkiAkfkls",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default elasticsearch input doesn't include document metadata such as type, index and id into the event. You need to enable it using `docinfo` flag and then specify where to get id in the elasticsearch output. See [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-inputs-elasticsearch-docinfo) for a detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

Worked with below in the input, section added

```
docinfo => true
    docinfo_target => "[@metadata][doc]"
```

and in the output section added

```
document_id => "%{[@metadata][doc][_id]}"
```